# Unmapped members were found ( DateTime )

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a Project with near 100 Classes and I am mapping Data Models/DTOs with AutoMapper. All Data Models are inherited from ZDataBase and all DTOs from ZDTOBase. But for only 6 of this Classes I get the following error:

```
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
===========================================
AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be mapped using the current configuration.
DateTime -> IZDataBase (Destination member list)
System.DateTime -> EasyLOB.Data.IZDataBase (Destination member list)
Unmapped properties:
LookupText
```

I get the error when I execute the following code:

```
{
    Console.WriteLine("FornecedorAnexo");
    FornecedorAnexo data = new FornecedorAnexo();
    FornecedorAnexoDTO dto = Mapper.Map<FornecedorAnexoDTO>(data); // <= ERROR
    data = Mapper.Map<FornecedorAnexo>(dto); // <= OK
}
```

I don't understand what is the relation between **DateTime** and **IZDataBase** in the error message. And, as I said above, only 6 classe show this error, all other map **LookupText**.
What could be the problem ?

I create the mapping using Profiles:

```
public static void SetupMappers()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
        // ZDataModel <-> ZDTOModel
        // EasyDG
        cfg.AddProfile<EasyDGDataAutoMapper>();
    });

    Mapper.Configuration.CompileMappings();

    Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}

public class EasyDGDataAutoMapper : Profile
{
    public EasyDGDataAutoMapper()
    {
        Assembly dataAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        Type[] types = dataAssembly.GetTypes();
        foreach (Type type in types)
        {
            if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ZDataBase)))
            {
                string dto = type.FullName + "DTO";
                Type typeDTO = dataAssembly.GetType(dto);

                CreateMap(type, typeDTO, MemberList.None);
                CreateMap(typeDTO, type, MemberList.None);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below you find my Classes:

```
public abstract class ZDataBase : IZDataBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [JsonIgnore] // Newtonsoft.Json
    [NotMapped] // MongoDB
    public virtual string LookupText { get; set; }
}

public partial class FornecedorAnexo : ZDataBase
{        
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int IdFornecedor { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public virtual int IdPessoa { get; set; }
    public virtual string Descricao { get; set; }
    public virtual string FileName { get; set; }
    public virtual string FileAcronym { get; set; }
    public virtual Fornecedor Fornecedor { get; set; } // IdFornecedor
    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; } // IdPessoa
}

public abstract class ZDTOBase<TEntityDTO, TEntity> : IZDTOBase<TEntityDTO, TEntity>
    where TEntityDTO : class, IZDTOBase<TEntityDTO, TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IZDataBase
{
    public virtual string LookupText { get; set; }
}    

public partial class FornecedorAnexoDTO : ZDTOBase<FornecedorAnexoDTO, FornecedorAnexo>
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }               
    public virtual int IdFornecedor { get; set; }               
    public virtual DateTime Data { get; set; }               
    public virtual int IdPessoa { get; set; }               
    public virtual string Descricao { get; set; }               
    public virtual string FileName { get; set; }               
    public virtual string FileAcronym { get; set; }
    public virtual string FornecedorLookupText { get; set; } // IdFornecedor
    public virtual string PessoaLookupText { get; set; } // IdPessoa
}

public class EasyDGDataAutoMapper : Profile
{
    public EasyDGDataAutoMapper()
    {
        Assembly dataAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        Type[] types = dataAssembly.GetTypes();
        foreach (Type type in types)
        {
            if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ZDataBase)))
            {
                string dto = type.FullName + "DTO";
                Type typeDTO = dataAssembly.GetType(dto);

                CreateMap(type, typeDTO, MemberList.None);
                CreateMap(typeDTO, type, MemberList.None);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set CreateMissingTypeMaps to false and try again.

Comment: I included **cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = false;** in **Mapper.Initialize** and the error does not show **LookupText** any more, but the **DateTime** error is still there: 

    "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

    Mapping types:
    DateTime -> IZDataBase
    System.DateTime -> EasyLOB.Data.IZDataBase"

Does anybody know what the **DateTime -> IZDataBase (Destination member list)** means ?

Comment: I finally isolated the error. If I have **NOT NULLABLE DateTime** property called **Data" in my Data Model like this **public virtual DateTime Data { get; set; }** I get the error. If I change the property to NULLABLE or change the name to something else, everything works fine. Is there any special meaning for a property called **Data** ( It means "Date" in Portuguese ) in AutoMapper ?

Comment: No. Probably AM just matches smth not obvious to you, but without a proper repro there's no way to tell.

Answer (score 0):

After the last comment I inspected the mapping and found the problem. There is a Constructor with a parameter named **data**. So, for any weird reason, AutoMapper mapped the **Data DateTime** property to the **data IZDataBase** parameter:

```
var expression = Mapper.Configuration.BuildExecutionPlan(typeof(ClienteAnexo), typeof(ClienteAnexoDTO));
string readableExpression = expression.ToReadableString();
readableExpression += "\r\n";

public ClienteAnexoDTO(IZDataBase data)
{
    FromData(dataModel);
}
```

To solve the problem I included **cfg.DisableConstructorMapping();** in my configuration.